# Is the word "access" pronounced differently as verb and noun?

Tags: pronunciation

Some background: I started to learn English in school since 1996 and the school only taught us British English, although sometimes the teachers also mentioned the difference between British English and American English.

**I roughly remember the word "access" are pronounced differently as a verb or a noun**, but I don't remember if this happens in British English or in American English. And what I remember is:

- "access", noun, is pronounced as "/'æk.ses/", with "a" pronounced as "/æ/" in "apple" and the pronunciation stress in the first syllable.
- "access", verb, is pronounced as "/ək'ses/", with "a" pronounced as "/ə/" in "accept" and the pronunciation stress in the second syllable.

But yesterday I was told they are **ALL** pronounced as "/'æk.ses/". Surprisingly (to me), I also found there is only one pronunciation in the dictionaries:

- [Cambridge Dictionary: access](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/access)
- [Longman Dictionary: access](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/access)

I doubt I remember it wrong, because when I learned the word many years ago, I made a lot of effort to make sure I pronounce them correctly when they play different parts in the speech. Also, our textbooks were published by British education companies with reputation so I don't think they were wrong.

**I tend to guess this is the evolution of the language over the past two decades? Does this make sense?** Because such changes happen in my mother tongue, too, that some word uses that I learned in the elementary school are seldomly used nowadays, and young people are no longer aware of the old uses.

**Or it could just be my bad memory..** If this is the case, I'll feel really awful: I had made so much effort to carve something completely wrong in my brain.

Comment: I do not remember anyone in the UK pronouncing it with stress on the last syllable. That covers a period well before you started learning English.

Comment: According to [this site](http://jianboge.com/d380664), the pronunciation with the stress on the last syllable is a mispronunciation

Comment: @mdewey I asked my other friends who went to the same schooling system as I did, and none of them remembered "access" has different pronunciations, so it must be my bad memory. Void in the other comment provides another interesting web page and I'm wondering maybe I learned it correctly in the first place but got misguided later.

Comment: @Void is our local pronunciation guru so I suspect your memory may have been playing tricks on you.

Comment: The full OED online gives both pronunciations for the verb: "British /ˈaksɛs/, /əkˈsɛs/, U.S. /ˈækˌsɛs/". But the 1989 edition of the OED gave only the first-syllable stress. I don't recall ever hearing /əkˈsɛs/, in any case.

Comment: @rjpond That's one disadvantage of using dictionaries: sometimes dictionaries don't reflect how real people use the language in real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Access' is pronounced the same as a verb and as a noun in British English.  Perhaps you were thinking of the difference between:

access - stress on first syllable;
accessible - stress on middle syllable

And similarly:
excess - stress on first syllable;
excessive - stress on middle syllable